# SendKeys.Send("{HOME}"), vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sendkeys

I am using  `SendKeys.Send("{HOME}")` in a `MaskedTextBox` to bring the cursor to the beginning of the textbox when the text is empty.

When I try to close the project the application freezes if it doesn't have focus.

How do I put this application in focus before I call `SendKeys`?

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.GotFocus
    Try
        SendKeys.Send("{HOME}")
    Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
        ' Do nothing
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

After that, it should give focus to the previous application and close.

Comment: Why are you calling  SendKeys.Send("{HOME}")?

Comment: To bring the cursor to the first char when there is a mask and it's not empty cause : SelectionStart, SelectionLenght doesnt work if there is a mask and the person click on the middle of the control

Comment: i am using SendKeys.Send("{HOME}") in a maskedtextbox to bring the cursor to the beginning when the text is empty <<< the way I understand this is you want to bring the cursor to the start in the textbox. see my answer and get rid of sendkey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{HOME} is like hitting the home key, this will not bring focus.

best thing to do to bring focus is to call the focus method on the text control. like textbox.focus();

Please include your page code, or an example of what is on the page.

MaskedTextBox1.Select(0,0)

Comment: Try to do a new projet with 
 Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.GotFocus
        Try
            SendKeys.Send("{HOME}")
        Catch ex As InvalidOperationException
            ' Do nothing
            ' SendKeys ne peut pas s'exécuter dans cette application, car l'application ne gère pas les messages Windows.
        End Try
    End Sub
then give the focus to another application and try to close your application

Comment: So your code will only fie if the textbox has focus. Not sure I 100% get what you are trying to do here. Let me try: You want your application to exit when your textbox has focus, then shift focus to another application?

Comment: No what happens is : When my maskedtextbox has the focus i want the cursor to be at the first position. 

My problem is : I open another application that application has the focus and then i try to close my first application. There is a deadlock and the computer freeze until u press control alt delete

Comment: If you want to try it. Make a new application put down a masked text box with a gotfocus event then type SendKeys.Send("{HOME}")  
open calc and try to close your application with the focus on calc. It will freeze.

Comment: try this and get rid of that sendkeys command on focus.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4fh98s.aspx

Comment: I've tried it doesnt work when u have a mask like : "CCCCC" and then the person click on the middle of it, it doesnt bring the cursor at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Give the textbox a focus **before** the SendKeys

```
MaskedTextBox1.Focus()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using visual basic login and it it is not running at run-time. Highlights SENDKEYS as the offender. Here is my code

Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    'check for correct password
    If txtPassword = "password" Then
        'place code to here to pass the
        'success to the calling sub
        'setting a global var is the easiest
        LoginSucceeded = True
        Me.Hide
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid Password, try again!", , "Login"
        txtPassword.SetFocus
        SendKeys "{HOME}+{END}"
    End If
End Sub